# View an image saved as a string in a picture box

Tags: c#, image, winforms, base64, picturebox

I converted an image to a string (base 64) and I want this string to be displayed as an image in a picture box in a windows forms project. How can I do that?

Comment: Just like every good car repair manual you've ever read.. *refitting is a reversal of removal*

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to know how you can display a text in a bitmap in a form that humans can read.

To be able to draw in an existing Bitmap you need a [Graphics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) object. You can get it using the static method [Graphics.FromImage(Image)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage?view=windowsdesktop-5.0).

Once you've got a Graphics object, you can use it to draw in the image. In this case you will use one of the overloads of [Graphics.DrawString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring?view=windowsdesktop-5.0)

There are a lot of items you didn't mention in your requirements.

- Does your picture box already show an Image and do you want this text to appear in this Image? And if the text must be on an existing Image, do you want a copy of it, or must the text be on the original image? Or do you want a new Image that shows only the text?
- Text in an Image has a Text, a Font (Arial or Times new Roman etc, size, bold, italic, etc), a Brush (Color of the text), and a Location in the Image. Where do you get those values from?

Let's assume you know where to get the Text, the Font etc, and you have properties

```
class TextToImageWriter    // todo invent proper name
{
    public Font Font {get; set;}
    public Brush Brush {get; set;}

    public void AddTextToImage(Image image, string text, PointF textLocation)
    {
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
        {
            graphics.DrawString(text, this.Font, this.Brush, textLocation);
        }
    }

    public Image CreateNewImageWithText(Image image, string text,
        PointF textLocation)
    {
        Image clone = (Image)image.Clone();
        this.AddTextToImage(clone, text, textLocation);
        return clone;
    }

    public Image CreateEmptyImageWithText(string text, int width, int height,
        Color backgroundColor, PointF textLocation)
    {
        Image image = new Bitmap(width, height)
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Bmp))
        {
             using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(backgroundColor))
             {
                 // fill the background
                 graphics.FillRectangle(brush, 0, 0, width, height);
                 // fill the text
                 graphics.DrawString(text, this.Font, this.Brush, textLocation);
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Of course, if you don't want to create a class, you can add the properties as parameters to the functions.

For simplicity I omitted the parameter validations (Image is not null, etc.)

Usage:

```
TextToImageWriter imageWriter = new TextToImageWriter
{
    Brush = ...
    Font = ...
};

Image imageToPutTheTextOn = this.PictureBox1.Image;
string text = this.GetImageText();              // maybe from a text box?
PointF textLocation = this.GetTextLocation();   // maybe from some mumeric boxes?

Image imageWithText = imageWriter.AddTextToImage(imageToPutTextOn, text, textLocation);
this.PictureBox2.Image = imageWithText;
```

}

Comment: Wow thank you very much!! You explained it really clearly!! You helped me a lot!! Thanks....